# SQL query to show missing records from another table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a list of names in the customers table. The second table contains events.
If a name is missing in the event table, it should get it from the customers.name table with "0" values.

Customers table:

```
|   NAME    |  ADDRESS  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   Chris   |    XXX    |
|   Tom     |    YYY    |
|   John    |    ZZZ    |
```

Events Table:

```
   NAME   |   QUANTITY   |
----------+--------------+
  Chris   |       2      |
  Tom     |       4      |
```

If one name is missing in the events table, the query should add it from the Customers table. (only for displaying, it should not be added to the records).

Result should be like this:

```
   NAME   |   QUANTITY   |
----------+--------------+
  Chris   |       2      |
  Tom     |       4      |
  John    |       0      |
```

I am using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a left join

```
select a.name, coalesce(b.quantity, 0) as  quantity
from Customers  a 
left join Events  b on a.name = b.name
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what a `left join` does:

```
select c.name, coalesce(e.quantity, 0) as quantity
from customers c left join
     events e
     on c.name = e.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or isnull

```
select a.name, isnull(b.quantity, 0) quantity
from Customers  a 
left join Events  b on a.name = b.name
```

Comment: there is no `IsNull` function in Firebird https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-conditional